# How can I debug this error: Property "CDbAuthManager.connectionId" is not defined

Tags: php, database, yii

I'm using the yi 1.1 application development cookbook and I'm trying to implement the RBAC(Role Based Access Control). The error that I'm getting says that CDbAuthManager is not defined which is strange because I tested the db connection and that works, and I'm defining the db in my main.php config file. Here is the code main.php:

```
// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
        'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rbac',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'myPassword',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
    'authManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
        'connectionId'=>'db',
        ),
```

And here is the RbacController.php file:

```
<?php 
class RbacController extends CController
{
        public function filters()
        {
            return array(
                'accessControl',
                );
        }

        public function accessRules()
        {
            return array(
                array(
                    'allow',
                    'actions'=>array('deletePost'),
                    'roles'=>array('deletePost'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'allow',
                        'actions'=>array('init', 'test'),
                        ),
                        array('deny'),
                );
        }
        public function actionInit()
        {
            $auth=Yii::app()->authManager;

            $auth->createOperation('createPost', 'create a post');
            $auth->createOperation('readPost', 'read a post');
            $auth->createOperation('updatePost', 'update a post');
            $auth->createOperation('deletePost', 'delete a post');

            $bizRule='return Yii::app()->user->id==$params["post"]->authId;';

            $task=$auth->createTask('updateOwnPost', 'update a post by author himself', $bizRule);
            $task->addChild('updatePost');

            $role=$auth->createRole('reader');
            $role->addChild('readPost');

            $role=$auth->createRole('author');
            $role->addChild('readPost');
            $role->addChild('createPost');
            $role->addChild('updateOwnPost');

            $role=$auth->createRole('editor');
            $role->addChild('readPost');
            $role->addChild('createPost');

            $role=$auth->createRole('admin');
            $role->addChild('editor');
            $role->addChild('author');
            $role->addChild('deletePost');

            $auth->assign('reader', 'readerA');
            $auth->assign('author', 'authorB');
            $auth->assign('editor', 'editorC');
            $auth->assign('admin', 'adminD');

            echo 'Done';
        }
        public function actionDeletePost()
        {
            echo "Post Deleted";
        }
        public function actionTest()
        {
            $post= new stdClass();
            $post->authId = 'authorB';

            echo "Current Permissions:<br />";
            echo "<ul>";
            echo "<li>Create post: ".Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('createPost')."</li>";
            echo "<li>Read post: ".Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('readPost')."</li>";
            echo "<li>Update post: ".Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('updatePost')."</li>";
            echo "<li>Delete post: ".Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('deletePost')."</li>";
            echo "</ul>";
        }

}

 ?>
```

I was under the impression that when using the db version of authManager, 'class'=>'CDbAuthManager', that the only way to set the hierarchy up was through yiic. But it doesn't say anything about yiic in the book  it just says "Now run init once to create the RBAC hierarchy". To me that means type in the controller/action pair into the url like this: http://localhost/rbac/index.php?r=Rbac/init.
IDK, maybe this is where I'm going wrong. The searched the net and can't really find any problems encountered similar to this one.

Edit:
I just attempted another approach. this time i created a console application command in /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/rbac/protected/commands/shell/RbacCommand.php
and I get the same error when I try to run it in the terminal:

```
exception 'CException' with message 'Property "CDbAuthManager.connectionId" is   not defined.' in    /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/yiiRoot/framework/base/CComponent.php:174
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/yiiRoot/framework/YiiBase.php(225):   CComponent->__set('connectionId', 'db')
#1  /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/yiiRoot/framework/base/CModule.php(371):  YiiBase::createComponent(Array)
#2  /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/yiiRoot/framework/base/CModule.php(86):  CModule->getComponent('authManager')
#3 /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/rbac/protected/commands/shell/RbacCommand.php (24): CModule->__get('authManager')
#4  /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/yiiRoot/framework/cli/commands/ShellCommand.p hp(147): RbacCommand->run(Array)
#5  /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/yiiRoot/framework/cli/commands/ShellCommand.p hp(99): ShellCommand->runShell()
#6 /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/yiiRoot/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(63): ShellCommand->run(Array)
#7 /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/yiiRoot/framework/console/CConsoleApplication .php(88): CConsoleCommandRunner->run(Array)
#8  /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/yiiRoot/framework/base/CApplication.php(158):     CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
#9 /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/yiiRoot/framework/yiic.php(33):  CApplication->run()
#10 /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/yiiRoot/framework/yiic(15):  require_once('/Users/scottmcp...')
#11 {main}
```

It says that connectionId is not defined and yet I've defined it and set it to a valid db connection. How can it NOT be defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is a little vague, I admit.  It's actually the opposite issue.  You're attempting to set connectionId and the error is telling you it can't do that because connectionId isn't a valid property in CDbAuthManager.  I believe it's actually:

```
'connectionID' => 'db',
```

the 'd' must be capitalized as well.

I hope that helps, it's really not the most clear error message.